# Python Extensions cannot see installed packages in DevContainer IDE

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I am trying to create a basic Development Container to use with VS Code.

I've been through a few iterations no of versions but keep coming up against the same issue, my VS Code extensions cannot seem to see what packages are installed in my venv.

Files in my workspace:
.devcontainer/devcontainer.json

```
{
    "name": "Existing Dockerfile",
    "context": "..",
    "dockerFile": "../Dockerfile"
}
```

venv/ containing pip installed pandas

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR .
COPY my_file.py .
```

my_file.py

```
import sys
import pandas

print(sys.path)
```

Output of sys.path incase relevant is `['/workspaces/yt', '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/workspaces/yt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages']`

The code executes fine when ran but in VS Code the linting tools raise an error that pandas is not accessed.

[image]

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason is that the environment in which the **pandas** library was installed is not the same as the environment you are currently using.

**Solution**

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette and search for **Python:Select Interpreter** to select a correct interpreter.

[image]

If the error is still not resolved, go ahead and try the following methods:

- Add configuration in **settings.json** to point to the pandas library.

  ```json
  // Just an example, please modify it to your own path
       "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        // Path to pandas library
        "C:\\WorkSpace\\PyTest0802\\.venv\\Lib\\site-packages"
    ],
  ```
- The most simple and rude method -- ***cancel this type of error*** (use with caution, this method will cause the prompt message that there is such an error to not be displayed)

  Add the following configuration to the **settings.json** file

  ```
        "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
            "reportMissingModuleSource": "none",
        },
  ```